# Одобрение IP при запросе доступа к хостингу

Tags: ip, хостинг

хочу на весь хостинг или на конкретный сайт установить ограничение по IP таким образом, чтобы при обращении к файловой системе с признаком "ЗАПИСЬ" (т.е. пытаются записать, загрузить или изменить какие-то файлы любыми каналами, через любые порты, кроме браузеров и порта 80, 8080 и аналогичным им) высылался email на почту админу со ссылкой подтверждения запрашивающего доступ IP (и доп.информацией по этому IP). Этот IP после клика по ссылке подтверждения записывается в список разрешенных (запрещено всё, кроме разрешенных).

как это сделать? есть варианты? в какую сторону копать?

Comment: Во первых зависит от операционной системы. во вторых почти не разрешимо. Запись на диск делают программы, которые запущены непосредственно на сервере и только они могут это контролировать. Вы не можете со стороны ОС узнать по чьему запросу программа производит запись, следовательно все такие ограничения надо вносить в код самих программ. гораздо проще вообще запретить доступ ко всем посторонним портам для всех

Comment: ок, так и сделаем